# Python 3 Server command update

Tags: python, python-3.x, http.server

I am new to Python so i wanted to ask you for help.

In old versions of Python to create a server which would not store any logs and its **standard output** was redirected to **dev/null** to **avoid saving information**, we executed the following instruction:

```
nohup python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

*> /dev/null*: Indicates that standard output is directed to /dev/null

*2>&1*: It indicates that all the errors that occur will not be stored in the log since they will be redirected to the standard output which we have redirected to /dev/null.

*&*: Indicates that this task will run in the background.

However, I don't know how to do it in the newer versions of Python, can you help me?

Tks guys.

Comment: The standard output / error redirection has nothing to do with Python - i.e., your command line would be identical to the example you've given regardless of the Python version

Comment: So the command would be:

nohup python -m http.server 80 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SimpleHTTPServer` module has been merged into `http.server` in Python >= 3.0. Try this one:

```
python -m http.server
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about the standard outputs? How can I modify them?

Comment: output redirection and ruuning in background are OS commands, not related to python. You can add `nohup` and `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` here as well.